# PDFBox Return Binary of Whole PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, binary-data

I'm using PDFBox to add some values to a form pdf which is already created. I can add the values fine and save it as a new pdf fine. However, my goal is to return the binary data so another program can handle the making of the PDF. With the code I have below it seems to be sending only the binary data of the values and not the original pdf. In fact the program I'm sending the data to makes the new pdf but it only contains the added values, no other part of the original pdf. How can I get it to send the binary of the pdf with the new values and not just the layer consisting of the new values.

```
File pdfer = new File("Form.pdf");
PDDocument documentnew;

 try {
 documentnew = PDDocument.load(pdfer);
 PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = documentnew.getDocumentCatalog();
 PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
 List<PDField> fieldList = acroForm.getFields();
 String[] fieldArray = new String[fieldList.size()];

 //Fill fields with information.

 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
 documentnew.save(out);
 System.out.println(out.toString());
 documentnew.close();
 }
```

Comment: Try calling `out.getBytes()`

Comment: Didn't work. Creates a corrupted pdf which is only 12k big. Also since out is already in a byte array I don't think it needs to be converted into byte format.

Comment: Out is not already in a `byte[]`. It's a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), and per the Javaodc *The data can be retrieved using toByteArray() and toString().*

Comment: Why would .save() to a fileoutputstream save the whole pdf with the layer of new values and saving it to a bytestream only save the layer with the values being added?